# Binary tree to Double Linked List in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I am trying to convert the Binary tree to Double Linked List in C#.

The order of nodes in DLL must be inorder traversal of Binary Tree.

Here is the code:

```
public void BSTtoDLL(ref Node root,ref Node head,ref Node tail)
        {
            if (root == null) return;

            BSTtoDLL(ref root.left,ref head,ref tail);

            if (tail != null)
            {               
                root.left = tail;
                tail.right = root;
            }
            else
            {
                head = root;
            }

            tail = root;

            BSTtoDLL(ref root.right,ref head, ref tail);
        }
```

But I get the stack overflow exception ?

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

While the inorder traversal is alright, the rest of your code is fundamentally wrong. While the `left` and `right` fields are a native part of the tree structure, you are misusing them for the double-linked list. The result is you are making the tree structure invalid, apparently introducing a circle which then causes the stack overflow.

In case you really need to keep those references *within* the `Node` class itself, you must maintain two pairs, like this:

- `treeLeft`, `treeRight` — for the tree data structure
- `listPrev`, `listNext` — for the double-linked list structure (note it's a common convention to call these references *previous* and *next*)

Plus a couple more things to consider:

- There's no reason to pass the root node with `ref`
- I'd suggest eliminating `ref`s at all, and instead operating on a `DoubleLinkedList` class
- Generally, I'd recommend decomposing the mechanics of data structures from the useful data payload, creating a `TreeNode<T>` and `ListNode<T>`, where `T` represents the useful data payload.

Comment: This is an algorithmic question,I am not supposed to maintain any extra pointers other than tree left and right.And If i dont pass ref objects how can i change the left and right pointers ?

Comment: Sorry It worked.I just removed ref in the root variable in the method.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode Left { get; set; }
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public TreeNode Right { get; set; }

    public TreeNode(int data)
    {
        this.Left = null;
        this.Data = data;
        this.Right = null;
    }
}
public class DLLNode
{
    public DLLNode Prev { get; set; }
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public DLLNode Next { get; set; }

    public DLLNode(int data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
public class Tree
{
    public TreeNode Root { get; set; }
    public Tree()
    {
        // Creating a dummy tree;
        Root = new TreeNode(10);
        Root.Left = new TreeNode(12);
        Root.Left.Left = new TreeNode(25);
        Root.Left.Right = new TreeNode(30);
        Root.Right = new TreeNode(15);
        Root.Right.Left = new TreeNode(36);
    }
}
public class DLL
{
    private DLLNode Curr { get; set; }
    public DLLNode Head { get; set; }

    public void FromTree(Tree t)
    {
        ProcessInOrder(t.Root);
    }
    public void Display()
    {
        while(Head != null)
        {
            Console.Write(Head.Data + ", ");
            Head = Head.Next;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessInOrder(TreeNode n)
    {
        if(n != null)
        {
            ProcessInOrder(n.Left);
            CreateDLLNode(n);
            ProcessInOrder(n.Right);
        }        
    }
    private void CreateDLLNode(TreeNode n)
    {
        DLLNode node = new DLLNode(n.Data);
        if(Curr == null)
        {
            Curr = Head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            Curr.Next = node;
            node.Prev = Curr;
            Curr = node;
        }
    }
}
DLL d = new DLL();
d.FromTree(new Tree());
d.Display();
```

Comment: Although your code might answer the question. It is always best to add some text to your post explaining what OP has left out.